# Does lock is required if "UI thread" and "DispatchTimer" both are updating the ObservableCollection list in Silverlight 4.0

Tags: multithreading, silverlight

1. I have an ObservableCollection list, this list is bind to ListView
   in  UI.
2. UI is starting a DispatchTimer to update the list with status(Test
   Pass or fail) of Test  periodically.
3. But UI thread has one more capabilityt to update the
   ObservableCollection list, by adding  OR removing item from that
   ObservableCollection list, if user chooses to Add or Remove certain
   Test from list.

So far, it is looking good. But can somebody please help me to understand how DispatchTimer and UI thread are not goign into deadlock. A per my understanding dispatchtimer is also a thread internally. Please forgive me if I am wrong.
If deadlock can occur on observablecollection then can we prevent by using lock() in  silverlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Remarks section on the [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) page on MSDN:

> Reasons for using a DispatcherTimer opposed to a
>   System.Timers.Timer are that the DispatcherTimer runs on the same
>   thread as the Dispatcher ...

The *same thread as the Dispatcher* is the UI thread, so you're safe.